# Create setenv.sh to set system property

Tags: java, linux, shell, tomcat

I have to use setenv.sh to set system properties. I am using Linux and Tomcat server 6.

As described [here](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2012/09/setting-environment-variables-and.html), I have created a setenv.sh in tomcat/bin and the only thing I added is:

```
export JAVA_OPTS =”-Dmyprojectvar.subname=value -Danothervariable=value -Danother.variable=value”
```

I don't know is this enough to set the properties. I just want to add three properties to tomcat as system property using setenv.sh. What should I do to complete it successfully? What are the steps for it?

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697584/setenv-sh-is-not-working) and there is answer given and I don't even understand the question. Do we need to set CATALINA_HOME and other properties somewhere in setenv.sh?.

Comment: Have you considered asking on http://serverfault.com?

Comment: Have you tried testing to see if these properties have been set?

Comment: shows ./catalina.sh: 1: export: : bad variable name when I am trying to run catalina.sh

Comment: I have changed " export JAVA_OPTS =”-Dmyprojectvar.subname=value -Danothervariable=value -Danother.variable=value” " to " export JAVA_OPTS="-Dmyprojectvar.subname=value -Danothervariable=value -Danother.variable=value" " But I couldn't run catalina.sh. After this I changed the code to " CATALINA_OPTS= ="-Ddeployment.type=denqa -DServiceRegistryLookupJNDI=10.3.1.206:1099 -DfastLogger.enabled=true" ". Now I can run catalina but the properties are not getting in the java program. I dont know is this the way to do it. Is it correct?

Comment: There is a space between the export JAVA_OPTS and "=" . I just removed it. Now I can run catalina.sh .  Now the code is 


export JAVA_OPTS="-Dmyprojectvar.subname=value -Danothervariable=value -Danother.variable=value"


Before  changing it was

export JAVA_OPTS =”-Dmyprojectvar.subname=value -Danothervariable=value -Danother.variable=value” 

I have removed space between export JAVA_OPTS & = (ie, export JAVA_OPTS=) and changed the ” to ". These two symbols are not equal.